# Erlang mode indenting

Tags: emacs, erlang, aquamacs

When I type a period after an `end`, this is the indenting I get:

```
a() ->
    receive
        {abc, Val} ->
            io:format("Val: ~w~n", [Val])
                end.
```

On the other hand, if I type a comma after an `end`, the `end` slides to the left:

```
a() ->
    receive
        {abc, Val} ->
            io:format("Val: ~w~n", [Val])
    end,
```

I wish a period would make the `end` slide to the left as well.

And, in the first example if I select the whole function clause and choose `Erlang > Indent > Indent Region` from the menu bar, I get:

```
a() ->
    receive
        {abc, Val} ->
            io:format("Val: ~w~n", [Val])
    end.
```

Why am I unable to get that indenting automatically? In fact, I think that after I type `end`, the `end` should automatically move to the left and line up with the `receive`--before I type any punctuation.  It shouldn't matter what punctuation follows.

Comment: I don't use Emacs anymore, but I believe the auto indentation was triggered only for characters in `electric-indent-chars`. See https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dIndentation.html. What is the value of `electric-indent-chars` in your emacs-mode buffer?

Comment: @Dogbert, where is my emacs-mode buffer?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant `erlang-mode` buffer, just any buffer that has an Erlang file opened (where this issue occurs).

Comment: @Dogbert, I get no match after `electric-indent-ch`.  Here is the list of possible completions: *Possible completions are:
electric-indent-just-newline
electric-indent-local-mode
electric-indent-mode*

Comment: @7stud post your question here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/ hope you get an answer. And take a look at Atom.io I'm using it for Erlang, it is good in my opinion.

Comment: @Aus, Thanks for the tip.  I've tried Atom.io before and it's too slow--like 3 second lags for autocomplete.  I moved to VS Code instead.  But, I like moving around a file with key strokes, like with vim.  I may have to try and get VS Code setup properly for Erlang.